# How to make operations more less divided?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a datatable (matricule, salary, number day and premium) with checkboxes and button validate, I want to calculate the sum value when I click on button validate but there is an error it gives me NaN for this value.

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="mytable">
  <tr>
    <th><input type="checkbox" id="check_all"></th>
    <th>matricule</th>
    <th>salary</th>
    <th>number day</th>
    <th>premium</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"></td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>5000</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="prime" class="form-control" value="0"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"></td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>6000</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="prime" class="form-control" value="0"></td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"></td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>7000</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="prime" class="form-control" value="0"></td>

  </tr>
</table>
<div class="form-group col-md-offset-5 ">
  <button class="btn btn-success add-all" type="submit" id="hide">Pointage men</button>
</div>
```

jQuery code for check all and get some values and calculate sum:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#check_all').on('click', function(e) {
    if ($(this).is(':checked', true)) {
      $(".checkbox").prop('checked', true);
    } else {
      $(".checkbox").prop('checked', false);
    }
  });
  $('.checkbox').on('click', function() {
    if ($('.checkbox:checked').length == $('.checkbox').length) {
      $('#check_all').prop('checked', true);
    } else {
      $('#check_all').prop('checked', false);
    }
  });

  // jquery code for display array :
  $("#hide").click(function() {
    var items = [];
    $("tr").each(function(i, r) {
      if (i > 0 && $(r).find("input").first().prop("checked")) {
        //sum = (((salary/24)*nbre)+premium)
        let sum = ((($(r.cells[2]).innerText / 24) * $(r.cells[3]).innerText) + $(r.cells[4]).find('input').val());

        items.push({
          "matricule": r.cells[1].innerText,
          "salary": r.cells[2].innerText,
          "nbre": r.cells[3].innerText,
          "premium": $(r.cells[4]).find('input').val(),
          "sum": sum
        })
      }
    });
    console.log(items);
  });
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `innerText` with `text()` and use `parseInt` for calculation.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#check_all').on('click', function(e) {
    if ($(this).is(':checked', true)) {
      $(".checkbox").prop('checked', true);
    } else {
      $(".checkbox").prop('checked', false);
    }
  });
  $('.checkbox').on('click', function() {
    if ($('.checkbox:checked').length == $('.checkbox').length) {
      $('#check_all').prop('checked', true);
    } else {
      $('#check_all').prop('checked', false);
    }
  });

  // jquery code for display array :
  $("#hide").click(function() {
    var items = [];
    $("tr").each(function(i, r) {
      if (i > 0 && $(r).find("input").first().prop("checked")) {
        //sum = (((salary/24)*nbre)+premium)
        let sum = (((parseInt($(r.cells[2]).text()) / 24) * parseInt($(r.cells[3]).text())) + parseInt($(r.cells[4]).find('input').val()));


        items.push({
          "matricule": r.cells[1].innerText,
          "salary": r.cells[2].innerText,
          "nbre": r.cells[3].innerText,
          "premium": $(r.cells[4]).find('input').val(),
          "sum": sum
        })
      }
    });
    console.log(items);
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered" id="mytable">
  <tr>
    <th><input type="checkbox" id="check_all"></th>
    <th>matricule</th>
    <th>salary</th>
    <th>number day</th>
    <th>premium</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"></td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>5000</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="prime" class="form-control" value="0"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"></td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>6000</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="prime" class="form-control" value="0"></td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"></td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>7000</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="prime" class="form-control" value="0"></td>

  </tr>
</table>
<div class="form-group col-md-offset-5 ">
  <button class="btn btn-success add-all" type="submit" id="hide">Pointage men</button>
</div>
```

*[Note: You can check input value is number or not using `$.isNumeric`.](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isNumeric/)*